# How to get big CSV files data into SharePoint Online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, modern-experience, csv

I have big CSV files on my local storage that I receive from an old system.
I would like to get all of this into the SharePoint Online list.
There is a way to paste everything with Quick Edit, but I think it is inefficient and unsafe.
Is there any other good way? 

Appreciate any ideas\Pointers.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your CSV has less than 20k rows, you could use SharePoint Online's "Create a list from Excel" feature. To do this, you will need to create a table from your CSV in Excel and save it as a spreadsheet. You can then follow these [instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-list-based-on-a-spreadsheet-380cfeb5-6e14-438e-988a-c2b9bea574fa#ID0EADAAA=Modern) using the spreadsheet.

Comment: [@Callum]:Thanks for the answer. Can your method be used to put data into an existing list?

Comment: Unfortunately, most of the options (both modern and classic) seem to refer to creating a new list rather than importing to an existing list. Could you use quick edit but copy and paste smaller amounts, instead of copy and pasting the whole spreadsheet in one go? Another option would be to write a PowerShell script to import the data, possibly saving the spreadsheet as a CSV first.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I think it is difficult to use quick edit because of the large amount of data.
I would like to consider the method of PowerShell. But I don't know PowerShell for SharePointOnline at all so is there any websites I should refer to?